# What are some three+ stage cyclical reactions that only go one direction?

Tags: reaction-order

I was imagining the origins of life and supposed that "humans are just a bunch of cyclical chemical reactions in a coat."  Which made me wonder, what sort of cyclical chemical reactions exist in nature?

For the purpose of this question, I'm defining ***cyclical*** as "three or more stages, only ever going in one direction."

I'm also defining ***stages*** as "distinct molecular arrangements which are not in-between each-other."  *Example*: picking up one Oxygen, then picking up another, then dropping both and starting over wouldn't count because step 2 is just sort of "in-between."

EDIT:  A lot of the context of this question was removed for being off topic, but I believe it is important: I did attempt to research this subject before asking, but I ran into a wall where I do not have any of the formal education required to know the correct key-terms for phrasing this question on any search engine.  And I still believe it is worth apologizing for that.

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE. I have removed extra sentences which were not part of the question. We just need your question and the research/effort you have done and references if any.

Comment: @Poutnik if you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.  Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 quite known examples of cyclic reactions:

1. 6-member ring of [CNO catalytic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) of hydrogen stellar fusion, which is used with stars more massive than the Sun, which uses [proton-proton chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain)
2. 12-member ring [Krebs/citric acid  cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle), used by mitochondria of eukaryot cells, which is central point of cell metabolism to produce ATP ([adenosine triphosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate)), a ready to use unit of energy.